# Is there a way in pyspark or spark sql to apply custom formula to current and next row and sum in an iterative fashion

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe df.

[image]

I want to apply a formula to this by partitioning at type.

revised W(t) = current of W(t)*2 + revised of W(t-1)*3.

For first row since there is no previous revised - it'll be
revised W1 (week) = current of W1*2  + 0

For remaining weeks,for eg.
revised W2 (week) = current of W2 * 2 + revised of W1 * 3

**expected output-**

[image]

How do we do this in spark or sql? Can we use Window.currentRow and Window.unboundedPreceding along with window func? or do we need to write a custom udf.

If not possible in pyspark, do we resort to pandas or using loops. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the `revised` column can be rewritten as

[image]

This formula can be evaluated with the help of a [window function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?pyspark.sql.Window#pyspark.sql.Window) and an [udf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?pyspark.sql.Window#pyspark.sql.functions.udf).

```python
#define a window that contains all rows for a type ordered by week
w = Window.partitionBy(df.type).orderBy(df["week"].asc()) \
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

#collect all values of past "current" values into an array
df = df.withColumn("tmp", F.collect_list(df["current"]).over(w))
#and reverse the array
df = df.withColumn("tmp", F.reverse(df["tmp"]))

#define an udf that applies the formula above on the array
calc = F.udf(lambda a: 2*sum([int(value) * (3 ** (index)) \
    for index, value in enumerate(a)]), T.LongType())

#run the calculation and drop the intermediate array
df = df.withColumn("revised", calc(df["tmp"])).drop("tmp")

df.show(truncate=False)
```

prints

```
+--------+----+-------+-------+                                                 
|type    |week|current|revised|
+--------+----+-------+-------+
|COMPUTER|w1  |100    |200    |
|COMPUTER|w2  |200    |1000   |
|COMPUTER|w3  |300    |3600   |
|COMPUTER|w4  |400    |11600  |
|COMPUTER|w5  |500    |35800  |
|SYSTEM  |w1  |120    |240    |
|SYSTEM  |w2  |150    |1020   |
|SYSTEM  |w3  |250    |3560   |
|SYSTEM  |w4  |450    |11580  |
|SYSTEM  |w5  |500    |35740  |
+--------+----+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Without udf, quite dirty but you can try.

First, I have calculated the index `i` that is starting from zero and collect it as a list until the current row. Second, I have gathered the `current` values into a list the same as the index.

The key point is that the order of the index array does not have what I want. So, In order the make it to the descending order, I have used the `array_sort` function with the custom ordering function.

After that, make it to struct array by using `arrays_zip`, and according to the brief formula of @werner's answer, I can aggregate the `revised` value.

I have worried about if there are more lines, the array could be more lengthy and could cause some memory problem, but anyway in this sample level it works.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('type').orderBy('week')

df2 = df.withColumn('i', collect_list(row_number().over(w) - 1).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('i', expr('array_sort(i, (left, right) -> case when left < right then 1 when left > right then -1 else 0 end)')) \
  .withColumn('w', collect_list('current').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('array', arrays_zip('i', 'w')) \
  .withColumn('revised', expr('aggregate(array, 0D, (acc, x) -> acc + x.w * 2 * power(3, x.i))')) \
  .select(*df.columns, 'revised')
df2.show()

+--------+----+-------+-------+
|    type|week|current|revised|
+--------+----+-------+-------+
|COMPUTER|  w1|  100.0|  200.0|
|COMPUTER|  w2|  200.0| 1000.0|
|COMPUTER|  w3|  300.0| 3600.0|
|COMPUTER|  w4|  400.0|11600.0|
|COMPUTER|  w5|  500.0|35800.0|
|  SYSTEM|  w1|  120.0|  240.0|
|  SYSTEM|  w2|  150.0| 1020.0|
|  SYSTEM|  w3|  250.0| 3560.0|
|  SYSTEM|  w4|  450.0|11580.0|
|  SYSTEM|  w5|  500.0|35740.0|
+--------+----+-------+-------+
```